# set a cmake variable if it is not changed by the user

Tags: cmake

How can i (re)set cmake variable only when it is not changed by the user?

I have this variables:

```
set(DIR "testdir" CACHE PATH "main directory")
set(SUBDIR ${DIR}/subdir CACHE PATH "subdirectory")
```

On the first run the variables are initialized to `testdir` and `testdir/subdir`.

When the user changed `DIR` and reruns cmake without changing `SUBDIR`, i would like to generate a new `SUBDIR` path, while i want to keep the `SUBDIR` path, when the user changed it.

So `SUBDIR` should be set to the new default value based on the new value of `DIR`, if `DIR` was changed and `SUBDIR` was never changed before.

Comment: You could use [`MODIFIED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_cache/MODIFIED.html) cache variable property, but the documentation says "Do not set or get". Maybe a better approach would be to check modification with `if` statements? So if `SUBDIR` is not equal `testdir/subdir`, do use `SUBDIR`.

Comment: The problem with the if statement is, that when i change ``DIR`` after the first configure, ``SUBDIR`` does not change (i.e. it stays with the old default).

Answer (score 5):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

You could use [`MODIFIED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_cache/MODIFIED.html) cache variable property, but the documentation says

> Do not set or get.

Maybe a better approach would be to check the modification with if statements:

```
set(DIR "testdir" CACHE PATH "main directory")
if (NOT DEFINED SUBDIR OR SUBDIR MATCHES "/subdir$")
    set(SUBDIR "${DIR}/subdir" CACHE PATH "subdirectory" FORCE)
endif()
```

Or you just don't put `DIR` inside `SUBDIR` and put the details into the description:

```
set(SUBDIR "subdir" CACHE PATH "subdirectory of main directory (see DIR)")
```

Answer (score 2):

Along with cache variable `SUBDIR` visible to the user, you may store another cache variable, say `SUBDIR_old`, which contains the last value of `SUBDIR` and marked as INTERNAL (that is not intended to be modified by the user).

Next launching of `cmake` you may compare values of `SUBDIR` and `SUBDIR_old`, and if they differ, then user has modified `SUBDIR`:

```
if(NOT DEFINED SUBDIR_old OR (SUBDIR EQUAL SUBDIR_old))
    # User haven't changed SUBDIR since previous configuration. Rewrite it.
    set(SUBDIR <new-value> CACHE PATH "<documentation>" FORCE)
endif()
# Store current value in the "shadow" variable unconditionally.
set(SUBDIR_old ${SUBDIR} CACHE INTERNAL "Copy of SUBDIR")
```

Problem with that approach that user **cannot** say:

> I have checked value of `SUBDIR` and found it **already correct**.

Without modification we assume that user don't bother about variable's value.

Comment: I thought about this as a solution, i wonder if there is a more clean way to do this. Cluttering the cache (and probably some advanced views) with such variables doesn't seem to be "the cmake way".