# Is it possible to figure out how cmake is called from cmake files and caches?

Tags: compilation, cmake

Within the build directory, I can see values of particular cmake variables using `ccmake ..` (assuming CMakeLists.txt sits on parent directory).

This becomes less effective when the original call to cmake has set many different variables in a large cmake project. For instance, if I call cmake like so:

```
cmake .. 
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="path_1;path_2;ect" 
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH="yet_another_path" 
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="yet_another_path"    
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=...    
-DPROJECT_SPECIFIC_FLAG_1=...    
-DPROJECT_SPECIFIC_FLAG_2=...
```

Is there anyway to be find out about this original call to CMakeLists.txt file from the cache or files? Is this string stored somewhere?

Comment: ccmake shows the content of CMakeCache.txt file. So I don't understand your question.

Comment: @usr1234567, True, but it doesn't clarify which of those variables are set by user and while are cmake/system defaults. I would like to know, when visiting a build folder, how I had called the cmake. In other words, get the string that I quoted in my question.

Comment: I don't know a way to achieve that. Sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately CMake doesn't output this information currently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set a cmake variable if it is not changed by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542381/set-a-cmake-variable-if-it-is-not-changed-by-the-user)