# Implement a conditional FORCE in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have implemented a scheme, that allows me to detect whether a CACHE variable `MY_VAR` has been changed by the user, much like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43545349/2912471). As there are a number of dependencies, instead of forcing a new value on a single dependent variable, I've introduced a new variable `MY_VAR_CHANGED`. To define a dependent variable one could do something like this:

```
if( MY_VAR_CHANGED )
  set( DEPENDENT_VAR "${MY_VAR}/ADDITIONAL_INFO" CACHE PATH "" FORCE )
else()
  set( DEPENDENT_VAR "${MY_VAR}/ADDITIONAL_INFO" CACHE PATH "" )
endif()
```

I'm using this code in many different places, so I was wondering if there is an elegant way to conditionally wrap the FORCE, e.g. by using something like the `? :` statement in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake lacks many features related to "inline" computation. Instead, you may always create a macro/function encapsulating behavior which you want:

```
# Straightforward macro, which removes code duplicates
macro(set_force_conditional cond_var)
    if(${cond_var})
        set(${ARGV} "" FORCE)
    else()
        set(${ARGV} "")
    endif()
endmacro()
```

Usage:

```
set_force_conditional(MY_VAR_CHANGED DEPENDENT_VAR "${MY_VAR}/ADDITIONAL_INFO" CACHE PATH)
```

(Normal variable's dereference looses `""` elements, so macro passes empty documentation string to the `set(CACHE)` command manually).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and especially the `""` hint. I came up with a similar solution but thought it might be error prone. So thanks for the confirmation, I can work with that :).